# Problema Leitura arquivo python Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, unicode

Pessoal tenho o meu script :

```
import sys
search = sys.argv[1]
ref_arquivo = open('C:/Zabbix/RelatorioErros.txt','r').readlines()[11:]
for line in ref_arquivo:
    if search in line:
        print(line[30:66],line[66:77],line[92:99],line[100:110])
```

ele funciona somente em arquivos UTF-8 porem ao executar o mesmo em uma maquina windowns quando executa a leitura do RelatorioErros.txt nao funciona pq o formado do txt esta em unicode o que fazer ?

Comment: Tem certeza que esse é o erro? Poderia postar a mensagem de erro aqui?

Comment: A *função* `open` possui o parâmetro `encoding` que você pode definir qual é a codificação utilizada na leitura do arquivo; por padrão ela é UTF-8.

Comment: @Woss o padrão não é sempre UTF-8; dos docs, `In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: locale.getpreferredencoding(False) is called to get the current locale encoding.`. Essa suposição de que é UTF-8 por default já me mordeu também!

Comment: @PedrovonHertwigBatista Bem lembrado.

Answer (score 1):

Se o arquivo estiver em utf-8 mesmo, é só declarar isso explicitamente ao abrir o arquivo no Windows.
Senão o Python vai usar a codificação padrão do sistema, que no caso é latin-1, e o conteúdo do arquivo vai ficar corrompido em memória (cada caractere fora da faixa ASCII, incluindo todos os acentuados, vai virar 2 ou mais outros caracteres nada a ver).

No caso, basta fazer:

```
ref_arquivo = open('C:/Zabbix/RelatorioErros.txt','r', encoding="utf-8").readlines()[11:]
```

(a outra parte envolvendo acentuação - leitura de `sys.argv[1]` deve ser tratada automaticamente no Python 3 - ele vai transformar da codificação usada no terminal para texto unicode internamente).